# Move most matched result up in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an application where user searches for another user. The most matched results should come higher up.

```
string name = txtSearch.Text;
string space = " ";

if(name.Contains(space))
{
    string[] FullName = txtSearch.Text.Split(' ');
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon))
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select UserProfile.City,  UserProfile.FirstName, UserProfile.LastName,UserProfile.Age where UserProfile.FirstName like '%" + FullName[0] + "%' or UserProfile.FirstName like '%" + FullName[1] + "%'  or UserProfile.LastName like '%" + FullName[1] + "%'";
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            dlContacts.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dlContacts.DataBind();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I am handling search work. txrSearch is id of text box where user types username to search and finally data is bound to datalist. Now I want to move the matches record up. Like if user types "Tom John" then Tom John name should come on the top and then remaining records with lower frequency of those keywords should come down. How can I do it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to store this information with the record, creating a rank column. Then every time you access some record update this field. The query that you just showed above must order this for the new rank field!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid SQL injection attacks, always use parameterized queries.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myFirstParam", FullName[0])
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mySecondParam", FullName[1])
```

your CommentText
(maby it is not ideal, but it works for you.)

```
SELECT 
 UserProfile.City,UserProfile.FirstName,UserProfile.LastName,UserProfile.Age 
FROM 
 UserProfile 
WHERE 
 UserProfile.FirstName LIKE '%' + @myFirstParam + '%' OR 
 UserProfile.FirstName LIKE '%' + @mySecondParam + '%' OR 
 UserProfile.LastName LIKE '%" + @mySecondParam + "%' 
ORDER BY 
 CASE WHEN UserProfile.FirstName LIKE '%' + @myFirstParam + '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
 CASE WHEN UserProfile.FirstName LIKE '%' + @mySecondParam + '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
 CASE WHEN UserProfile.LastName LIKE '%' + @mySecondParam + '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
DESC
```

what about

- i have three names
- i have three names
- i use upper/lower case
- i enter space and not type a second word
- ....?

Comment: Your suggestion worked. It also works for lower/upper case. And yes I didn't think about rest of your questions :/ .. Anymore suggestions you can give in this regard??